# Shiny app using bigquery to be deployed on google cloud run

Tags: shiny, google-bigquery, dockerfile

I developed an R-shiny app that uses bigquery data fetched via bigrquery packaged. The authentication works via a JSON service account key, generated via google cloud. This works fine locally but I face problems when dockerizing the shiny application to deploy it on google cloud run. Any experiences with dockerizing a shiny app that uses bigquery running on google cloud run_

```
# Use the official R image from Docker Hub
FROM rocker/shiny:4.1.0

# Install necessary R packages
RUN R -e "install.packages(c('shiny', 'googleCloudStorageR', 'googleAuthR', 'bigrquery'))"

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Shiny app files to the container
COPY ./app /app

# Expose the port the Shiny app runs on
EXPOSE 3838

# Define the command to run the Shiny app
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/app')"]
```

It is not clear to me where the JSON key should or should not be stored.